# c++: issue defining a class in a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

In the constructor of an object I have the following code:

```
ConfigReader::ConfigReader(){
    TiXmlDocument doc(CONFIGURATION_FILE_LOCATION);
    configDoc = TiXmlHandle(&doc);
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following warning:

```
no matching funciton for call to 'TiXmlHandle::TiXmlHandle();
```

`configDoc` is a `TiXmlHandle` defined in my h-file as a private variable for the class.  Both of the classes are from the TinyXML C++ project, but that's hardly relevant. The compiler is correct that there is no default constructor for `TiXmlHandle`. However, since I'm constructing the TiXmlHandle using a valid constructor this, in theory, shouldn't matter.

So what is the syntax, if any, to tell C++ to not bother trying to create the `TiXmlHandle` with a default constructor since I'm just going to override it?

I appologize for the simple question, I know that this is the sort of thing I should be able to look up but I've tried and not been able to stumble upon the answer.

Comment: As a side note, did you forget a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the line with `configDoc = blah blah`, or is it just a typo in the question?

Comment: I didn't copy paste this (computer with code doesn't have internet access).  So it was a typo, and I wouldn't be surprised if there were others since I reworte it by hand fast.

Comment: Another side note, you're creating a temporary variable `doc` on the stack and trying to pass its address. That would trigger undefined behavior, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`configDoc` is being default constructed and then, later, you are trying to copy assign it to `TiXmlHandle(&doc)`. A `TiXmlHandle` apparently can't be default constructed, so this doesn't work. The default construction is happening implicitly because you haven't overridden it by using the member initialization list.

You use the member initialization list like so:

```
ConfigReader::ConfigReader()
    : configDoc(/*args*/)
{
    // ...
}
```

Obviously, to pass the proper argument to `configDoc` in that location you'll have to restructure your code a bit. Perhaps your `TiXmlDocument` should be a member too. There are a lot of refactoring options; You can figure that part out yourself.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew the cuase of the problem, but not the solution.  As I suspected there was a simple syntax to do what I wanted, but I didn't know it.  However, I have one follow up question.  If I didn't define my default construcotr, instead using an "openConfigFile" method I don't get this error.  Why doesn't the default consturctor generated by the compiler run into the same issue trying to define the TiSmlHandler?

Comment: EitanT: I tried the syntax you mentioned, and it didn't work.  Specifically I got an argument saying "taking address of temporary" which is of course valid since the XmlDocument would go out of contaxt as soon as the constructor returned.  Yes that means the code I originally posted above is also flawed for the exact same reason (the document goes out of scope while the handler is still pointing to it).  Just in case I haven't shown my C++ ignorance enough with this question, there is more proof! :).